# What is the "bag on a stick" Hercules is holding in this picture?

Tags: ancient-rome, identification, greek-mythology

The [picture](https://www.greekmythology.com/Myths/The_Myths/Labours_of_Heracles/labours_of_heracles.html) in the upper right of this page depicts Hercules/Heracles (or is it King Erystheus?)  sitting on a chair or a throne, with the Nemean lion's skin and a club.  [Archaeolovers clarifies why they've swapped clothing](https://archaeolovers.wordpress.com/2021/07/18/hercules-and-omphale-mosaic/)

What is the stick with something which looks like a bag on its end that he is holding? Certainly it's not a bindle.

It looks vaguely familiar and appears to be a symbol of nobility, but I can't tell for sure.

Here's a clip from the original mosaic on [wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Mosaic_with_the_Labors_of_Hercules%2C_3rd_century_AD%2C_found_in_Liria_%28Valencia%29%2C_National_Archaeological_Museum_of_Spain%2C_Madrid_%2815457383995%29.jpg):
[image: Man in a dress, holding a curious object stands before a reclining female form holding a club and wearing a lion's skin]

The full image along with its source in the URL:
[image: The prior image in context]

Whoever is depicted on the left side seems to also wear a skin or fabric and hold a weaving apparatus (the Fates?).

Feel free to give more context to that particular scene.

Comment: It actually looks like a marotte or bladder-on-a-stick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object in question in the right hand of the seated person, identified in the question title as Hercules, but later revealed to be in reality Omphale, queen of Lydia, is *not* unambiguously identifiable.

Other scholars have attempted this, but could not reach a *definitive* conclusion. It may indeed represent a flail, but if does, the actual form is a bit unusual for the practical purposes.

When interpreting this picture with an emphasis on the one instrument in her right hand, it seems noteworthy the he has too 'feminine' objects in his hands, while she has *his club* leaning casually within her left hand or arm, while the instrument seems to be hers *wielded at* Hercules.

Together with a certain peculiarity of this privately ordered *amuse oeil* this leads to the least common denominator reading:

> She appears covered with the clamid, veils her head with the leonine skin, while in her left hand she carries the claub and in her right she wields what has been interpreted as an instrument of punishment. […]
>
> As we have already mentioned, despite having been described on several occasions, no study has questioned the intentionality underlying the choice of the theme of the mosaic. In the construction process of a house, the ornamental apparatus selected responds to the cultural level of the owner; the higher the level, the greater the initiative in the choice of the motif, the lower the level, the greater the active participation of the workshop master. Iconographic studies reveal to what extent we are contemplating scenes copied from a cardboard or copy book, adapting pre-existing models with a certain dose of personalism, or if we are faced with a work that is the fruit of creativity (Neira 2003: 98), in our case we consider that it is a combination of motifs coming from the owner's selection.
>
> — Tamara Peñalver Carrascosa: "Más allá del mito: una lectura social del mosaico de los Doce Trabajos de Hércules (Liria, Valencia)*
> Beyond the myth: A social interpretation about the mosaic of the Twelve Labours of Hercules (Liria, Valencia)", Archivo Español de Arqueología 2018, 91, págs. 163-181. [doi](https://doi.org/10.3989/aespa.091.018.008)

Answer (score 22):

I can't find anything specific saying this, but my suspicion is that is meant to be a flail/scourge. Also, the question has the subjects a bit wrong.

As a bit of background, the central mural is depicting Hercules' year of servitude to Queen (regnant) [Omphale of Lydia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphale). During that time, the myth has it that she did her best to wound his male pride by doing things like forcing him to help with the (women's work) of knitting, and taking his lion-skin cloak and club for herself.

So what you see in this central mural bit is Omphale sitting on her throne (with breasts exposed, so you get the gender), and the much more swarthy Hercules standing, holding a couple of spools of wool spinning thread. You can even see the thread leading from one to the other. Omhpale for her part is clearly wearing a lion skin, and holding a very un-royal looking club.

Here are 3 more bits of art depicting this same event from [her Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphale). As you can see, Hercules being more swarthy, and Omphale either having or being given his club and lion skin cloak are common themes.

[image: Montenegran Frescoe][image: Roman Fescoe][image: Constantin Dausch Sculpture]

So now how about the object in her right hand? I believe this is most likely supposed to be a flail. This was a traditional symbolic pictoral element to [represent royalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crook_and_flail) in the ancient near east, particularly representing the ruler's dominion over their subjects. In this case it would be serving double duty showing both that the holder was a reigning monarch, and that Hercules specifically, who she's brandishing it at, was her slave. Its usually shown with a crook held in the left hand, but in this picture Hercules' pilfered club is standing in for that implement.

Here's an Egyptian artifact showing a crook and flail. Note particularly the bend in the middle, the length of the flail half being nearly identical to the stick half, and the larger width at the end of the flail half (presumably to accommodate more scourging elements).

[image: Crook and Flail]

Comment: Note: Since I can't find any sources on this, I'm honestly not sure if the flail bit is my own unique supposition, or a supposition that's so obvious to someone who knows the material that nobody ever bothers writing it down. I suspect the latter, but I've been wrong before.

Comment: It doesn't look like a weapon, unless a bag of pot pourri on a stick to ward off evil smells counts as such.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - The one on the Egyptian sarcophagus doesn't look much like a weapon either ... or even a farming implement. And the crook doesn't look very practical for use on actual sheep either. Its meant to be symbolic, not functional.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm not so sure.  Consider the modern weapon called a ['blackjack' or 'sap'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baton_(law_enforcement)#Blackjacks_and_saps).

Comment: @JimmyJames - I looked into that as a possibility for this answer too. There is actually a version called a "hinged club" that there's some small resemblance to the picture. However, its almost impossible to find pictures of them (thanks golfers!). But I'm thinking the fact that its relatively unknown would also have made using one in a representational mosaic very bad iconography, so that's almost certainly not what its supposed to be. Plus the proportions, at least in the one picture on your linked WP page, are much further off than for the flail.

Comment: @JimmyJames - As for the device pictured being practical...no doubt it would hurt being hit with one. Its so short it would be trivial to stay out of range, but given that a monarch is wielding it, avoiding the blow may not be considered an option.

Comment: @T.E.D. That was kind of my thought.  Similar to how the mace became a symbol of power, the flail would be more of a non-lethal symbol of authority over subjects, figuratively and possibly literally used to dole out punishment.  A bit of conjecture but it makes more sense than a holding a bag of something on a stick like a hobo.

Comment: A little cursory searching comes up with the flail (or 'nekhakha') as being interpreted by some in this way i.e. a tool used to manage herds like a whip is used with a horse.  Doesn't seem like there's a definitive answer though..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crook_and_flail: "In the interpretation of Toby Wilkinson, the flail, used to goad livestock, was a symbol of the ruler's coercive power: as shepherd of his flock, the ruler encouraged his subjects as well as restraining them."  I've never heard of him before but he appears to have some credentials, and has written a bunch of books.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's a beehive on a stick. The story of Hercules and Samson (from the Bible) have a common motif. Samson found a beehive in the carcass of a dead lion, but I can't seem to find a related story for Hercules. I'm surprised that I can't seem to find any definitive evidence of this interpretation, though. If I look at it long enough, I can convince myself easily that it is a beehive more than any other thing.

One article that explains how the story of Samson seemed to be inspired by the story of Hercules is here:
https://isthatinthebible.wordpress.com/2018/11/23/shamgar-son-of-anat-and-israels-age-of-heroes/

I wish I could find a more authoritative source, but I found this reddit that summarizes the Herakles-figures motif quite well.
https://www.reddit.com/r/AcademicBiblical/comments/dglzhz/is_it_possible_that_the_story_of_herculesheracles/

Comment: It would be a better answer if you could find some evidence linking the two tales.

Comment: Interesting pull though.